# Repeating CodeBehind code in .NET

Tags: .net, function, code-behind

I have a column on my web site for showing recent news.

Here's the code I use in my CB file.

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    public partial class LearnMore : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Define database connection
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=\\SqlExpress;Database=;Integrated Security=True");
            // Create command
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, title FROM news", conn);
            // Open connection
            conn.Open();
            // Execute the command
            SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            // Read and display the data
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                newsLabel.Text += "<a href='NewsEntry.aspx?ID=" + reader["ID"] + "'>" + reader["Title"] + "</a>" + "<br />";
            }
            // Close the reader and the connection
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

I'm using the above code in **every** CodeBehind file.

Would it make more sense to have this in just one place?
And if "YES!", how do I go about this?

Many thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it *would* make sense.

Create a base page that has this in it and have all other pages inherit from that.

```
public partial class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  // code that is used in all pages
}

public partial class LearnMore : BasePage
{
  // code for LearnMore
}
```

Comment: Hey Oded. I'm a bit stuck. Trying the above method gives me a compilation error "Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BasePage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" I have got a BasePage.aspx.cs with the code from the OP in it. Something obvious I'm doing wrong? Many thanks

Comment: @user644978 - Check the namespaces, they should be the same in both classes (or you need to import a `BaseClass` namespace with a `using` directive).

Comment: Wow, I was worried you wouldn't reply :) OK, I'll check right now. Back in a second.

Comment: At the head of my 'LearnMore.aspx' I have: `<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="BasePage.aspx.cs" Inherits="BasePage" %>` - is this correct?

Comment: @user644978 - No, it isn't. It should be `CodeFile="LearnMore.aspx.cs" Inherits="LearnMore"`.